# Trouble getting href - Instagram automation

Tags: python, selenium, instagram, hashtag

I am not the first and not the last one who got into this: cannot get all hrefs from instagram. Although it is common I cannot get all hrefs from a class and all solutions I tried so far desperately failed. So, would appreciate a hand or a punch into the right direction.

I am searching for a hashtag:

```
hashtags = '#hashtag'
search.send_keys(hashtags)
time.sleep(2)
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

link_list=[]

links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Nnq7C weEfm')

for link in links:
    link_list.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
    
    print(link_list)
```

There are several upper level classes that select all pics by neither gives me href.
I can get href from `v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w` - the class defing an individual pic on the search results page. Despite there are 33 `v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w` on the page I get only one href.

[image: how firefox console looks like]

Comment: To get the href values you need to xpath /a to an a tag and then get_attribute('href') on it.

Comment: !!! Worked perfectly as magic!

Comment: In fact it is th only solution, that extracts hrefs. Yet, it gives me all hrefs in in the page, includin suggested friends and even neighbour hashtags. I wonder how to sort out only those i need by the necessary class? ``` if ``` returns none again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 links=[x.get_attribute("href") for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w']/a")]
```

Just use /a on the class and get the hrefs like so. I'd find a more suitable xpath since that class name looks dynamic though.

Comment: `hrefElements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w']/a")))

elements_link = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in hrefElements]` worked in the end